# Equality in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

In Introduction to Axiomatic Set Theory by G. Takeuti and W. M. Zaring chapter 3

It is given: Definition of equality as: $a=b \Leftrightarrow (\forall x)[x \in a \Leftrightarrow x \in b]$.

And it is written this is incomplete in sense variable $x$ does not occur in $a = b$ and hence we have not made clear which of infinitely many formulas, equivalent under alphabetic change of variables, we intend $a=b$ to be abbreviation for.

But the problem is easily resolved by specifying that $x$ is the first variable on our list of variables(given in alphabetical order) that is distinct from $a$ and $b$.

I get the point what problem is but didn't get point how it got resolved from last sentence

Comment: Maybe they meant for every x in a implicitly?

Comment: @Sushil: I think of these axioms as patterns that mostly can be interpreted by common sense. What I don't think is that they fixating the ultimate definition of sets. We have a mental picture guiding our creativity and the formal axioms tells what is allowed.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what the problem is. The formula has two free variables, $a,b$ and a bounded variable, $x$. The formula states that $a=b$ if and only if for every assignment into $x$, we have an element of $a$ if and only if we have an element of $b$.

We didn't write infinitely many formulas. Just one. And the axiom of extensionality is when we quantify over $a$ and $b$ with universal quantifiers.

The "problem" that we didn't specify whether $a$ is $x_1$ or $b$ is $x_2$ is nitpicky and seems like insisting on unnecessary details. Here's a rule of thumb:

Whenever the variables don't match the superstrict rules, we pick the least index possible each time. End of story.

Comment: As much as I can understand it is written that as everything is set. And x is variable which stands for sets. It is bounded in this formula. But as there are infintely many variables(corresponding to alphabetical change of variables) we have not mentioned which formula. And what you have written in last 4 lines can you please explain a little bit more.

Comment: And in book axiom of Extensionality is mentioned as: (fe x)(fe a)(fe b)[a=b and x in a iff x in b]    where fe is 'for every'. And it seems me much better than given in Naive Set theory by Paul halmos

Comment: I really don't understand your question here. You seem to say "Well, there are infinitely many variables, and we can use any of them instead of $x$, so which one do we use?". The answer is simple. We use $x$.

Comment: Can you please have a look at book. I think I just misunderstood it. But I have written lines exactly from book. And the thumb rule you said can you please explain with an example. I think this would clarify something to me

Comment: No, I don't have the book, so I can't take a look. If you have quoted something verbatim from the book, you should place it in a quote block, making it easier to distinguish which part is a quote, and where is your question in all that.

Comment: okay I got your point the problem is only we didn't specify where a or b is in list. And thumb rule is that we pick least index possible. But as written 'Choose x as the first variable on our list of variables(given in alphabetical order) that is distinct from a and b' We will apply thumb rule on a and b (or on x as written in book

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the **standard convention** in formalizing mathematical theories is that the universal quantifiers in front of formulas can be omitted.

See Sara Negri & Jan von Plato, [Proof Analysis : A Contribution to Hilbert’s Last Problem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107417236) (2011), page 41 :

> Very many axioms are universal in form. They can be written either as universally quantified formulas, or as formulas with free parameters, as in the following axioms for equality:
>
> > $a=a \quad \quad \forall x (x=x)$.

If you want to be "totally formal", you have to follow the specifications of the language.

See Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122384520) (2nd ed - 2001), page 69-on.

Thus the above definition can be rewritten as :

> $\forall a \forall b [a=b \leftrightarrow \forall x(x \in a \leftrightarrow x \in b)]$.

If you want to "normalize" it according to the specifications [see **EXAMPLES** in the language of set theory, page 71] we have to write it as :

> $(\forall v_1 (\forall v_2 (=(v_1,v_2) \leftrightarrow (\forall v_3(\in(v_3,v_1) \leftrightarrow \in(v_3,v_2))))))$.

This is the correct formula, according to Enderton's book.

As noted by Enderton, page 72 :

> > The finished product is not nearly as pleasant to read as the version that preceded it. As we have no interest in deliberately making life unpleasant for ourselves, we will eventually adopt conventions allowing us to avoid seeing the finished product at all.

---

*Note*

Your reference is to :

- Gaisi Takeuti & Wilson M.Zaring, [Introduction to Axiomatic Set Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387053026), (2nd ed - 1982), page 7 :

> **Definition 3.1.** $a = b \leftrightarrow (\forall  x)[x \in a \leftrightarrow x \in b]$.

We have to review language's specifications, page 4 :

> The language of our theory consists of:
>
> Free variables: $a_0, a_1, \ldots$,
>
> Bound variables: $x_0, x_1, \ldots$,
>
> A predicate symbol: $\in$,
>
> [...]
>
> > We will use $a, b, c$, as *metavariables* whose domain is the collection of free variables, and we will use $x, y, z$, as *metavariables* whose domain is the collection of bound variables.

Thus, according to Takeuti's specifications, the formula is :

> > $[a_0 = a_1 \leftrightarrow (\forall x_0)[[x_0 \in a_0] \leftrightarrow [x_0 \in a_1]]]$.

Takeuti does not explicitly states the convention about universal closure of axioms.

Due to **Axiom 5**, page 6 :

> $(\forall x)\varphi(x) \rightarrow \varphi(a)$

we can always rewrite the axiom prefixing the universal quantifiers in order to obtain a closed formula and then, by *modus ponens*, derive the "open" version of it.

Comment: Ok the problem is with subformula 'a=b' because we have not mentioned which out of infinitely choice for a and b we taking. But last 4 lines in question about solving problem what did they stand for?

Comment: In book they are not going totally logical as you mentioned. This is next line from book: 'Having thereby shown that we can specify a particular formula we will not bother to do so in this book' I think this is exactly what you told. But last 2 lines in questions(which are from book not mine) I am still not able to understand

Comment: Sorry I don't think i get much as I have just started studying logic. But let me write what I understood. a, b and x(in our def) are metavariable whose domain is collection of variables in our language means they stand for free variables. Now problem in def is that variable x does not occur in a=b. So we don't know what a=b is abbreviation for. But as we are not being totally formal, we use rule of thumb as mentioned in previous comment and specify x as least metavariable in our list distinct from a and b. Am I correct?

Comment: @Sushil: I think you have a point, because in a way a and b are predicates that are thought of as objects through a binary relation: a(x)$\leftrightarrow$ x $\in$ a.

Comment: @Mauro Allegranza Sorry ehat two formula are equivalent you have written. Which one you are one is for every and one without for every. or anything elae. i don't get anything sorry

Comment: @Lehs - Absolutely **NO**. According to Takeuti's specifications $a$ is a metavariable standing for *free*  vars $a_i$ while $x$ is a metavar standing for a *bound* var $x_i$. $a(x)$ is not a correct expression of the language.

Comment: @Sushil - I'm saying that from Def3.1 written as $\forall x_1 \forall x_2(...)$, using Axiom 5 and modus ponens you can derive $[a_0=a_1 ↔(...)$ and vice versa using Rule 2.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Okay this much okay. So what I written in last comment is completely okay or there is some problem

Comment: @Sushil: I didn't mean the equivalence to be literally, just that $'\!\!\in\! a'$ is like a sort of predicate in post-fix notation, informally. Formally, there are completely different rules to apply.